# Using Pi 3 for wireless display/miracast

Tags: pi-3, wireless, display

I would like to connect my Pi 3 to a ceiling mounted projector, and send display content to it wirelessly from a Windows PC. Using something like Miracast. I have found [Piracast on github](https://github.com/codemonkeyricky/piracast), but that is only for Pi 2, with a specific dongle. Is there anything similar for Pi 3 just using the built-in wifi instead of the dongle?

I plan to use a direct device to devive connection, with the Pi 3 set up as a wireless access point using hostapd.

Comment: The Raspberry 2 and 3 should for all practical purposes be the same machine.  Try with Piracast and see if it works.

Comment: Piracast only works using a certain wifi dongle, we don't have said dongle and want to use the built in wifi on Pi 3.

Comment: Fixed your question then.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I have developed [lazycast](https://github.com/homeworkc/lazycast) that is designed to work on Raspberry Pi 3. lazycast follows (most of) the wifi display specification (commercially known as Miracast) and uses wifi p2p (commercially known as WiFi Direct) to set up a connection. I have tested it with Windows 8.1 and 10 sources. It requires no modification (using the built-in wifi) to the hardware and minimum modification to the system. I believe that this is exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Does this work also with RPi Zero W as I believe it uses the same wifi chip as RPi 3?

Answer (score 2):

PiCAST 3 is out, but from what I can tell only streams YouTube videos? I may be wrong, but I haven't have much experience with it.
You can find it here:

https://github.com/lanceseidman/PiCAST

shairport-sync is an iDevice version which will allow you to setup AirPlay to stream audio to your device. However, if you are lucky enough to still be on iOS 8.xx you will also have the ability to mirror your display. Unfortunately, with the newest updates from Apple, the mirror functionality doesn't work from any devices running 9.xx +
You can find it here:

https://github.com/mikebrady/shairport-sync

UV4L is another option. However, it looks as though it requires a bit more work to setup each time and isn't as simple as shairport-sync, but it does allow for video 'casting'. You can find it here:

http://www.linux-projects.org/uv4l/

OSMC has built casting that may work for an android device, being an apple user I am unable to test whether or not it works, but others have reported it working:

https://discourse.osmc.tv/t/cast-youtube-to-kodi-r-pi/7237

Comment: Thanks for answering. I want to mirror what is on a PC screen (I will clarify this in the question), so neither PiCAST 3, shairport-sync or OSMC are suitable. UV4L looks like it could be promising, so will follow that up.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/codemonkeyricky/piracast/issues/13) the wifi-chip of the rpi3 does support p2p connections (WiFi direct). So the hardware is in principle capable of Miracast/Wireless Display.

Piracast seems abandoned but there is a project working on a Miracast implementation for GNU/Linux Systems: [MiracleCast](https://github.com/albfan/miraclecast).

Comment: Thanks, this project has kind of stalled, but will add MiracleCast to the avenues to try out when we kick it off again.

Answer (score 1):

Providing that you've set up your Pi's wifi network [(otherwise follow a tutorial on how to use hostapd)](https://frillip.com/using-your-raspberry-pi-3-as-a-wifi-access-point-with-hostapd/), you can easily use the DLNA function built right into Windows to send media content from your PC to your Pi.

First, you want to be running Kodi on your pi. Then [enable the UPnP client](http://kodi.wiki/view/UPnP/Client#UPnP_client_settings) and connect to your pi's network from the PC. Then you want to right click media files that will now appear with a cast to option. Make sure you have enable network discovery! For streaming with other programs such as Edge, [follow this](http://www.howtogeek.com/233663/how-to-cast-websites-to-your-tv-from-microsoft-edge/).

Comment: I gave this a try, it worked for media files on W10 and Android, but I really want to be able to send the whole screen, like you can with Miracast.

Comment: That could certainly be done but you will experience latency issues and problems with reliability without actual Miracast compatible dongles and devices. @LC1983

Comment: Thanks. We have actual Miracast kit now. However I will try and get it working on the Raspberry Pi as a learning exercise.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [UV4L demo](https://youtu.be/yhxnAmJsT_E?list=PLT2HCg4Nbo1upDmqPFxyT8koQwvCcUOph) and [this post](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=91&t=169896&p=1091568&hilit=uv4l#p1091568) and the following posts on the Raspberry Pi forum for a working command line. I think UV4L is actually the simplest way, as it does not require any configuration. It can cast the screen, a tab, a window and the camera from Firefox plugin-free after having set the proper authorization (i.e. the host where UV4L is running)  in the config/preferences.