# Can i connect using WiFi Direct to use smartphone as monitor. No internet access!

Tags: display, connection, internet, android, wifi-direct

I would like to know how to connect my RPi 3 model B+ to my Samsung Galaxy s10e (sm-g970u) using WiFi Direct to use my smartphone as the display screen as i have **NO** **internet access** at my home and i can't turn on the TV at night because of the brightness and everyone's asleep. Is this even possible? Maybe a better solution? I also have a Lenovo Laptop i can use as the monitor display if that helps. Please help. Thank you guys & gals.

Comment: I could show you how to connect by WiFi-Direct but I don't understand "*to use my smartphone as the display screen*". Your TV is connected with an HDMI cable but the smartphone only wireless. That is a huge difference. Do you mean to use **ssh** (text console) or **VNC** (GUI)?

Comment: This could be one for Android.SE or, more likely, https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ to look for an app on your phone that could receive a video stream via WiFi Direct..

Comment: A GUI desktop is not simply a video stream any more than a picture of a car is a car, so that will not help.  The OP is looking for a **remote desktop client,**  as suggested by Ingo. I think there are a few options but the easiest is probably [RealVNC](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=realvnc), for which there are Android clients -- I haven't used it myself so can't say any more about it, but if you start digging through those linked questions (and look elsewhere online, RealVNC is not just used on the Pi)...

Comment: ...you should be able to figure it out, and if there is anything  you don't understand or that doesn't work, ask a more specific question.  Keep in mind the android side of things is probably better researched on an android forum, eg. https://android.stackexchange.com/ Also note: If you don't need a GUI and are fine just working on a text console, `ssh` is simpler.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Pi 3 for wireless display/miracast](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/60855/using-pi-3-for-wireless-display-miracast)

Answer (score 1):

WiFi Direct is not specific to video: you will be running a multimedia protocol such as Miracast on top of it. There are a few projects out there, the most promising being [miraclecast](https://github.com/albfan/miraclecast), though none of them worked [for me](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/108696/did-anyone-get-a-miracast-display-working-with-a-pi-4) (on a Pi 4). Perhaps you will be more lucky with your Pi 3.

Note that the opposite task (sending the video stream *to* the Pi) seems to be [much easier](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/60855/using-pi-3-for-wireless-display-miracast).

Answer (score 0):

You can use either SSH och VNC, depending on your objective and both ways has mobile apps.

**VNC** - Will give you a graphical desktop on your mobile phone.

Ref.: https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/get-back-to-my-pi-from-anywhere-with-vnc-connect/

**SSH** - will give you a command line terminal on your mobile phone.

Ref.: https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/tinkernuts-beginners-guide-to-ssh/

Just remember that SSH needs to be enabled on your raspberry pi, use `raspi-config` for that task.

Ref.: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/raspi-config.md